# pg gem install on Mac OS Lion with rvm

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems, rails-postgresql, pg

```
212-178-13-214:~ igorfedoronchuk$ gem install pg Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:48: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
/Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:853:in `block in find_header'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:852:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:36:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/pg-0.12.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/pg-0.12.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

Postgres was downloaded and installed from http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/
(version 9.1)

I was trying to install postgres with brew - no results.

How to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the ruby1.9.1-dev installed? I don't know how to install it on OSX, but it solved that problem for me on Linux (I got it through the package manager).

Comment: rvm is used now
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ i686 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]

Comment: I'm still having an error, even after using homebrew install postgresql. It's the same error. ruby version is ruby-1.9.2-p290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message ("You have to install development tools first.") says it all. Install Xcode first, and then try installing the pg gem.

Also, you don't have to install a third-party PostgreSQL on Lion, as it's already included.

Comment: I just installed version 4.2.1 and I'm still getting the error.  Ideas?

Comment: Look at the 'mkmf.log' in the ext/ directory of the gem. It usually contains clues about what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and here is where I found my [resolution](http://gilmation.com/articles/install-and-test-the-postgresql-gem-with-ruby-version-manager/)

Hope this helps!