# Unable to install Rails extconf.rb failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm getting the below error when I'm installing it.

Please note, I have installed the latest Xcode and installed command line tools, and I'm using OSX 10.8.4. I've installed Ruby 2.0.0 as well.

```
-bash-3.2$ sudo gem install rails
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/WillieTran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/WillieTran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
--with-atomic_reference-dir
--without-atomic_reference-dir
--with-atomic_reference-include
--without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
--with-atomic_reference-lib
--without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/WillieTran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/WillieTran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
from /Users/WillieTran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in `try_run'
from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/WillieTran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.12 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/WillieTran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.12/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What do you have in `/Users/WillieTran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.12/ext/gem_make.out`?

Comment: I've had this same problem too, in the gem_make.out is just a text version of what he pasted.

Answer (score 12):

I had similar problem and it gets solved by installing command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 6):

The symlinking did not solve the problem for me.  I uninstalled my ruby that I previously had installed using rvm by typing `rvm uninstall ruby-2.0.0` and then I typed `rvm requirements`. This command found that I needed a few other things, such as gcc46. It's strange that the gcc compiler was needed, even though I had installed the xcode command line tools, and gcc was most definitely installed on my system.

So, if none of the usual methods are working, give `rvm requirements` a shot!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's a same problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344821/gem-install-pg-doesnt-work-on-osx-lion).

Try `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/{llvm-,}gcc-4.2` and `gem install rails` again.

By the way, you're in your own home directory, you don't have to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this with `ruby 2.5.3` and was able to install cairo by calling:

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig gem install cairo -v '1.15.2'`

Took a while to find something that worked, as I already had the command line tools installed, and am using `asdf` not `rvm`.

Thanks to this thread for helping with the fix: https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/issues/259#issuecomment-59751807