# failed to install bson_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, bson-ext

```
hs-mac-air:~ zuohaisu$ sudo gem install bson_ext -v '1.9.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bson_ext:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for asprintf()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
/Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The     compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:894:in `block in have_func'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
from /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:893:in `have_func'
from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson_ext-1.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/zuohaisu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson_ext-1.9.2/ext/cbson/gem_make.out
```

I tried to install bson_ext but always failed. can somebody help?
My rails version is 1.9.3
My Mongo shell version is 2.4.3
My rails version is 4
It is said that some libraries missing. what does that mean?

Comment: The error message `You have to install development tools first.` means that a compiler wasn't found in your path. You likely need to install either XCode Command Line Tools or gcc. The `gem_make.out` log referenced at the end of the error should have more details. The solution should be similar to [this question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344821/gem-install-pg-doesnt-work-on-osx-lion).

Answer (score 4):

try

```
gem update --system
gem install bson_ext
```

if all else fails download the gem
http://rubygems.org/gems/bson_ext
and add it to your gemsets manually

Comment: Worked.  I was missing gcc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and installed gcc to resolve, thanks for the hint by gspatel.

`yum install gcc`